# The requested resource does not support http method 'POST' with proper decoration - Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have looked over a ton of '*method not supported*' errors on StackOverflow but none of the suggested solutions have worked for me.  I have a very basic Web API with a web method that on Post request always returns the error

> *'The requested resource does not support http method 'POST''*

when called from PostMan with a POST request.

There are no httpprotocols defined in my web.config.  I have tried with and without the Route and also without the `[FromBody]` in the parameter passed but all permutations have failed.

Request = `http://myURL/api/XMLInput`, the body of the request has an XML which I am processing.

**Controller**

```
[Route("XMLInput")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult PostXMLInput([FromBody] XmlDocument xml)
{
    XMLInput xmlInput = new XMLInput();
    xmlInput.XML = xml.InnerXml;
    return null;
}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provided Request `http://myURL/api/XMLInput` would not match your action unless the action has a route that maps correctly

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class MyController : ApiController {

    //POST api/XMLInput
    [Route("XMLInput")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult PostXMLInput([FromBody] XmlDocument xml) { ... }
}
```

OR

```
public class MyController : ApiController {

    //POST api/XMLInput
    [Route("api/XMLInput")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult PostXMLInput([FromBody] XmlDocument xml) { ... }
}
```

Source: [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#add-routes)

Comment: This solved the problem that I was having, thank you for your answer.